# Simple Trig Equation - Blank Mind

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm trying to set a simple trig equation equal to zero, for use with the first derivative test, etc. I have:

$-2(\sin\theta+\sin2\theta)$

So, I need to get

$\sin\theta=-\sin2\theta$

I'm drawing a complete blank here.

If it matters, but it shouldn't the original equation I've derived from is:

$f(\theta)=2\cos\theta+\cos2\theta$

I guess what I'm really asking for is a refresher in solving trig equations, if someone doesn't mind. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.

Wikipedia's [list of trig identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) should prove very helpful :)

Comment: Great, thanks! I gave up too early on the simplification!

Comment: And remember: you can't divide both sides of the equation by $\sin\theta$ unless $\sin\theta \ne 0$.  So you need to say: _Either_ $\sin\theta=0$ _or_ $\dots\dots$.